# Extracting text from an xml field

Tags: php, xml

Unfortunately the title makes it seem easier than it actually is.

I have an xml file that contains specific fields. They have been set to type="text" so that I can put a bit of text within a text box.

What I'm needing to do is extract whatever is in this text box, using php, to echo out where I need it to go.

I've been looking for a good hour now and have found various answers of kinds but none of them really replicate what I'm trying to get at, hence the need for a question!

Another thing I have used is the function file_get_contents, but again, this didn't work.

Here's the xml file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <config>
<fields name="params">
    <fieldset name="basic">
        <field name="field_speaker" type="text" label="Speaker" size="50" description=""></field>           
        <field name="field_hours" type="text" label="Number Hours" size="50" description=""></field>    
    </fieldset>         
</fields>   
  </config>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So what text are you trying to get out of it? And what have you tried?

Comment: well, annoyingly, to make it more complicated I'm using Joomla! CMS. i'm trying to extract the content that i put in the field_speaker text box

Comment: So you're trying to get this out of the file? 

name="field_speaker" type="text" label="Speaker" size="50" description""

Comment: PHP has a lot of inbuilt functionality for working with xml files. Look into [simplexml](http://php.net/simplexml)

Comment: Yes and no, sorry i'm crap at explaining things. the type="text" generates a box that i can type into. i need to extract whatever i type into this generated box.

Comment: Joomla is storing those parameters in its database, not in that xml-file. Use `$this->params->get('field_speaker')` to read those values. You might want to retag your question with `joomla`